# mac OS microphone only works when using Siri, works fine on bootcamp

Tags: macbook-pro, bootcamp, audio, siri, microphone

As the title says the mic only works in Mac OS when using Siri in any other application it is just muted, [image]the input level in system setting is always 0 as shown in the picture unless I'm using Siri. The mic works just fine on Windows 10 through bootcamp which leads me to believe it is not a hardware problem.

I'm on mac OS Sierra 10.12.3, I tried resetting SMC didn't make a difference.

Comment: I guess you could start troubleshooting the problem by creating a fresh user account to establish whether it is a user or system level problem if you haven't already done this.

Comment: I tried with a fresh user account still the same problem

Comment: Can you name any of the other apps you tested the mic with?

Comment: @AndrewMagdy I'd start by thinking about whether I have installed applications that relate to audio. Have you installed any audio plugins or other applications that specifically rely on CoreAudio or have you ever needed to change your mic input for some reason?
To add to this, you may want to check the settings in /Applications/Utilities/Audio MIDI Setup.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out one of the mics was dead which caused this problem, the mic died after I used a pin to clean it. I now know that after I killed the second mic by cleaning it.

Answer (score 7):

I had the same issue recently, and i found a seemingly stupid fix to it.

Go to system preferences, keyboard, and access the dictation and try using it on any document. The default to using dictation on my mac was double tapping Fn button. Strangely enough my dictation feature worked and typed what i spoke on the screen as Siri did. Then, go back to your input devices and check if that "permanently" fixed ur input issue; microphone should now also work without dictation being active.

Comment: OMG. This fixed the problem for me. Thank you!  And once again, OMG Apple.

Comment: I think the system is blocking the input of other apps while the dictation is in progress and it somehow toggled always on (even when the dictation is not being used). This might be the reason behind the solution. For my case, I just switched dictation off and the mic started to work fine.

Comment: Weird fix but it worked for me ! Thanks !

Comment: This works!  Amazing!  I had this issue, and Apple Store geniuses were baffled -- they recommended trading in for a new laptop after they tried replacing the I/O board and that didn't help.  They also tried creating a separate user, etc., but none of those standard solutions worked.  THANK YOU for this!

Comment: It works on Monterey 10.12.5! This has been giving me fits for months. Now I don't have to invade the Genius Bar!

Comment: It worked on me when I activated the dictation. Then it stopped working, I then disabled again and started working again!!! Apparently it doesn't mind if you enable or disable, both options fix the issue.

Answer (score 2):

I cleaned out the tiny little microphone holes by a pin and it worked, per [this message on ASC](https://discussions.apple.com/message/26976035#message26976035).

Answer (score 0):

In case the problem is not dirt, I found a workaround, turn on voice control and then in the top menu select stop listening.

This will not change anything in your mac's behaviour but mic will start working, at least for me.

Comment: The issue, per the OP, was physical damage.  That said, how can dirt cause a failure in macOS, but not in Windows (Bootcamp)?

Comment: yep absolutely, this looks to me a driver issue which only responds to mac native applications like siri or voice control, but otherwise disable the mic.